Finding the natural frequency from the transfer function magnitude
Studying Steady Sinusoidal State circuits and I have a question regarding RLC circuit.
Given that the transfer function for the voltage across the capacitor is given by -
$$
H(j\omega) = \frac{1}{R+j\omega L +\frac{1}{j\omega c}}
$$
Magnitude is
$$
|H(j\omega)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\omega ^2LC)^2+w^2C^2R^2}}
$$
Is it possible to find the natural frequency by finding the \$ \omega \$ for which the magnitude is maximal?
I tried that and couldn't get a definite answer, might be bad math from my side...
Thanks in advance!

That can't be the usual unitless V/V transfer function. It must be the admittance transfer function of the series circuit current divided by the applied voltage. Otherwise the dimensional analysis just doesn't work out. It simply cannot be the voltage across the capacitor. So show your work and the schematic, please.

First let me say that the natural frequency \$\omega_N\$ is, in general, not the same as a resonant/anti-resonant peak, \$\omega_p\$.
The natural frequency is a parameter of a 2nd order system, not an actual oscillation. If the damping ratio,\$\zeta\$, is zero, then the system will oscillate at the natural frequency.
The system in the question could be over or critically damped in which case there is no peak, but\$\omega_N\$ is still present as it is a parameter, not an oscillation.
\$\omega_N\$ is easily found by inspection of the magnitude equation. No need for a lot of math.
As a student, you need to work the following starting with the general form:
$$
H(s)=\frac{b_0}{s^2+a_1s+a_0}
$$

Review how to convert to the parametric form using \$\zeta\$ and \$\omega_N\$.
Convert to sinusoidal steady state by substituting \$s=j\omega\$.
Manipulate into a form that matches your \$|H(j\omega_N)|\$.
Compare the denominators. \$\omega_N\$should be obvious.



Is it possible to find the natural frequency by finding the ω for
which the magnitude is maximal?

The natural resonant frequency may be some distance away from the magnitude resonance as per this graph for a 2nd order resonant circuit taken from my basic website: -

So, basically, the magnitude resonance is \$\omega_n\sqrt{1-2\zeta^2}\$ where \$\omega_n\$ is the natural resonant frequency governed by the values of L and C. The damping ratio is \$zeta\$ and this will have a value dependent on your precise RLC circuit. Here's a 3D representation showing one of the poles: -


Well, you stated that your transfer function is given by:
$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}{\displaystyle1-\omega^2\text{CL}+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}}\tag1$$
So, for the magnitude we get:
$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(1-\omega^2\text{CL}\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}}\tag2$$
Now, let's find:
$$\frac{\displaystyle\partial\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|}{\displaystyle\partial\omega}=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\text{C}\left(1-\left(\text{CL}\right)^2\omega^4\right)=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\text{CL}}}\tag3$$
Which gives:
$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\text{CL}}}\right)\right|=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\tag4$$
